Is the proof of the theorem shown valid, and, if not, how might the proof be fixed?

Theorem …
If $n$, $k$, and $a$ are positive integers such that all $n$ terms of the arithmetic progression $a+0k$, $a+1k$, $a+2k$, … $a+(n-1)k$ are odd primes, then $k$ is divisible by every prime less than $n$ .

If $n$ were $1$ or $2$, there would be no primes less than $n$ and the theorem would be vacuously true.  Thus, we may henceforth assume that $n \ge 3$ .

One proof offered for the above theorem is the following …


In the above proof, it is claimed that $(i - j) \lt p$.  However, is it not possible that $i = p$ and $j = 0$, in which case $(i - j) = (p - 0) = p$ ?  And, if this concern invalidates the proof, how might the proof be fixed?


You're correct the proof you've shown is flawed. In particular, with $i = p$ and $j = 0$ then, as you've stated, $r_p = r_0$ since the terms are $a + pk$ and $a$, respectively, with a difference of $pk$, but there's no requirement that $p \mid k$. Also, this proof doesn't even use, at least not explicitly, the important condition that all of the terms are odd primes.
Here's one way the proof may be fixed. Since the terms are all odd primes, then $k$ must be even, so $2\mid k$. Assume there's at least one odd prime $p \lt n$ where $p \nmid k$, and choose the smallest such prime, call it $p_1$. The offered proof does show that the remainders then repeat exactly every $p_1$ terms, so the first $p_1$ terms must have all of the possible remainders modulo $p_1$, i.e., from $0$ to $p_1 - 1$ inclusive (note this forms a complete residue system modulo $p_1$). Consider the term which is divisible by $p_1$. Since it's prime, that term must be $p_1$.
If it's the first term, i.e., $a = p_1$, then since $p_1 \lt n$, the $p_1 + 1$'th term is in the sequence, with it being $a + p_1k = p_1 + p_1k = p_1(k + 1)$ and it's $\gt p_1$, i.e., it's not a prime. However, if the term which is $p_1$ is not the first term, then there's an immediately previous term, with this being an odd prime, say $p_2$, so it's a factor of $k$ (so $k = p_{2}m$ for some integer $m \gt 0$) as $p_1$ was the smallest odd prime which wasn't. However, then the next sequence term after it is $p_2 + k = p_2 + p_{2}m = p_2(m + 1)$, i.e., it's divisible by $p_2$ and $\gt p_2$, so it's not a prime (also, that term should be $p_1$, so that's another contradiction).
This shows there can't be any such smallest odd prime $p_1$ where $p_1 \nmid k$, so there are no such odd primes. As stated earlier, since $2 \mid k$, then this proves that all primes less than $n$ divide $k$.

Note the Green-Tao theorem states that, for all positive integers $n$, there exist arithmetic progressions of primes with $n$ terms. The theorem you've quoted shows that, for each such $n$, we have $k$ being an integral multiple of $(n - 1)\#$, where $\#$ refers to the primorial, i.e., the product of all primes up to, and including, $n - 1$.

How it ist that that the  "if" statement is ever true? so that you get primes at any instance of a+jk this would say that there exist n primes with equal distance k?

@trula I'm unclear on what you're asking about, such as what "if" statement in particular you're referring to. If it's to the theorem itself, which appears to be case from your second sentence, then yes it's stating we can get $n$ primes at equal distance $k$. For example, with $n=5$, the primes of $5, 11, 17, 23, 29$ are all $k=6$ apart from each other. Note the Green-Tao theorem shows there's no upper bound on what $n$ may be. If you're asking about something else, such as about in my answer, then please clarify.

Thanks, the Green Tao theorem I did not know.
